# flask blueprint template folder

Tags: python, flask

My flask app layout is:

```
myapp/
    run.py
    admin/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        pages/
            index.html
    main/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        pages/
            index.html
```

_***init*_**.py files are empty. **admin/views.py** content is:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='pages')

@admin.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**main/views.py** is similar to **admin/views.py**:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='pages')

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**run.py** is:

```
from flask import Flask
from admin.views import admin
from main.views import main

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')
app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/main')

print app.url_map

app.run()
```

Now, if I access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/`, it correctly displays admin/index.html.
However, `http://127.0.0.1:5000/main/` shows still admin/index.html instead of main/index.html. I checked app.url_map:

```
<Rule 'admin' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> admin.index,
<Rule 'main' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> main.index,
```

Also, I verified that index function in main/views.py is called as expected.
If I rename main/index.html to something different then it works. So, without
renaming, how can achieve that 1http://127.0.0.1:5000/main/1 shows main/index.html?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As of Flask 0.8, blueprints add the specified template_folder to the app's searchpath, rather than treating each of the directories as separate entities. This means that if you have two templates with the same filename, the first one found in the searchpath is the one used. This is admittedly confusing, and is poorly documented at this time (see [this bug](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/266)). [It seems](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/10/14/i-m-having-problems-with-blueprints/#efc0ec75d030563ab815ac667fadbea2) that you weren't the only one that was confused by this behavior.

The design reason for this behavior is so that blueprint templates can be easily overriden from the main app's templates, which are first-in-line in Flask's template searchpath.

Two options come to mind.

- Rename each of the `index.html` files to be unique (e.g. `admin.html`
  and `main.html`).
- In each of the template folders, put each of the
  templates in a subdirectory of the blueprint folder and then call
  the template using that subdirectory. Your admin template, for example, would be `yourapp/admin/pages/admin/index.html`, and then called from within
  the blueprint as `render_template('admin/index.html')`.

Comment: Having similar problem. I wish this was handled differently out of the box. Changing location of static folder works just fine with serving files but template get's overridden if the same file already exists.

Comment: As jay chan had pointed out the most simplest way is to store templates inside the main templates folder so that admin.html is stored under `myapp/templates/admin/index.html`

Comment: Why don't you just change `template_folder` to `"admin/pages"` or `"main/pages"`?

Comment: @JanKaifer I've done the same, include other template is ok, but while using extends, it keep priority to the root template level, after 6 year, any chance to get rid of this?

Comment: Is this bug fixed or not yet? using `flask1.0` and still having problem with template directories inside blueprints

Comment: @DarkSuniuM it's still there, you can't use same name template, really bad design

Comment: When creating blueprint, what is the purpose of specifying the template_folder then? I had expected that the render_template would look into that folder only

Comment: I tried the second bullet. ('admin/index.html') did not work. Gave Template not found.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to linqq's good suggestions above, you can also override the default functionality if needed. There are a couple ways:

One can override `create_global_jinja_loader` in a subclassed Flask application (which returns a `DispatchingJinjaLoader` defined in flask/templating.py). This is not recommended, but would work. The reason that this is discouraged is that the `DispatchingJinjaLoader` has enough flexiblity to support the injection of custom loaders. And if you screw your own loader up, it'll be able to lean on default, sane functionality.

So, what is recommended is that one "override the `jinja_loader` function" instead. This is where lack of documentation comes in. Patching Flask's loading strategy requires some knowledge that doesn't seem to be documented, as well as a good understanding of Jinja2.

There are two components you need to understand:

- The Jinja2 environment
- The Jinja2 template loader

These are created by Flask, with sensible defaults, automatically. (You can specify your own [Jinja2 options](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment), by the way, by overriding `app.jinja_options` -- but bear in mind that you'll lose two extensions which Flask includes by default -- `autoescape` and `with` -- unless you specify them yourself. Take a look at flask/app.py to see how they reference those.)

The environment contains all of those context processors (e.g., so you can do `var|tojson` in a template), helper functions (`url_for`, etc) and variables (`g`, `session`, `app`). It also contains a reference to a template loader, in this case the aforementioned and auto-instantiated `DispatchingJinjaLoader`. So when you call `render_template` in your app, it finds or creates the Jinja2 environment, sets up all those goodies, and calls `get_template` on it, which in turn calls `get_source` inside of the `DispatchingJinjaLoader`, which tries a few strategies described later.

If all goes according to plan, that chain will resolve in finding a file and will return its contents (and some [other data](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.BaseLoader.get_source)). Also, note that this is the same execution path that `{% extend 'foo.htm' %}` takes.

`DispatchingJinjaLoader` does two things: First it checks if the app's global loader, which is `app.jinja_loader` can locate the file. Failing that, it checks *all* application blueprints (in order of registration, AFAIK) for `blueprint.jinja_loader` in an attempt to locate the file. Tracing that chain to the very end, here is definition of jinja_loader (in flask/helpers.py, `_PackageBoundObject`, the base class of both the Flask application and Blueprints):

```py
def jinja_loader(self):
    """The Jinja loader for this package bound object.

    .. versionadded:: 0.5
    """
    if self.template_folder is not None:
        return FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(self.root_path,
                                             self.template_folder))
```

Ah! So now we see. Obviously, the namespaces of both will conflict over the same directory names. Since the global loader is called first, it will always win. (`FileSystemLoader` is one of several standard Jinja2 loaders.) However, what this means is that there's no truly simple way to reorder the Blueprint and the application-wide template loader.

So, we need to modify the behavior of `DispatchingJinjaLoader`. For a while, I thought there was no good non-discouraged and efficient way of going about this. However, apparently if you override `app.jinja_options['loader']` itself, we can get the behavior we want. So, if we subclass `DispatchingJinjaLoader`, and modify one small function (I suppose it might be better to reimplement it entirely, but this works for now), we have the behavior we want. In total, a reasonable strategy would be the following (untested, but should work with modern Flask applications):

```py
from flask.templating import DispatchingJinjaLoader
from flask.globals import _request_ctx_stack

class ModifiedLoader(DispatchingJinjaLoader):
    def _iter_loaders(self, template):
        bp = _request_ctx_stack.top.request.blueprint
        if bp is not None and bp in self.app.blueprints:
            loader = self.app.blueprints[bp].jinja_loader
            if loader is not None:
                yield loader, template

        loader = self.app.jinja_loader
        if loader is not None:
            yield loader, template
```

This modifies the strategy of the original loader in two ways: Attempt to load from the blueprint (and ONLY the currently executing blueprint, not all blueprints) first, and if that fails, only then load from the application. If you like the all-blueprint behavior, you can do some copy-pasta from flask/templating.py.

To tie it all together, you have to set `jinja_options` on the Flask object:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
# jinja_options is an ImmutableDict, so we have to do this song and dance
app.jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy() 
app.jinja_options['loader'] = ModifiedLoader(app)
```

The first time a template environment is needed (and thus instantiated), meaning the first time render_template is called, your loader should be used.

Comment: Does this method allow for template inheritance?

Answer (score 16):

twooster's answer is interesting, but another problem is that Jinja by default caches a template based on its name. Because both templates are named "index.html", the loader won't run for subsequent blueprints.

Besides linqq's two suggestions, a third option is to ignore the blueprint's templates_folder option all together and place the templates in respective folders in the application's templates directory.

ie:

```
myapp/templates/admin/index.html
myapp/templates/main/index.html
```

Comment: This answer (though Twoosters was well solved) makes the most sense here IMO because if you are trying to achieve the local-priority effect, then you are NOT using blueprint-level templates for their intended purpose-- to be extended from and/or overridden by application specific templates. Simpler is usually better. (and in this case, much more in line with the nature of the intention).

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, you say Jinja has cache problems when two templates are named `index.html` but then recommend an alternative that still has two templates named `index.html`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The difference seems to be that the two new index.html files are differentiated by their path under the template folder, as opposed to both being directly under their blueprint's template folder, like 'myapp/admin/templates/index.html' and 'myapp/main/templates/index.html'.

Comment: It would limit the way to organize template folders, for example if i have multiple modules with template in each folders. Have to name template file differently is quite a bad design for jinja

Comment: The only reason I don't like this, is that it undermines one of the reasons for using Blueprint.  It is supposed to prevent naming conflicts, in this case it creates one that shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Tks @linqq, your method really works well here, besides I made a better solution by the decorator.

Attention here, don't import the render_template function like this:

```
from flask import render_template
```

You should import the flask module like this:

```
import flask
```

Then, make this block of code at the top of your router file:

```
def render_decorate(path_prefix):
    def decorate(func):
        def dec_func(*args, **kw):
            arg_list = list(args)
            arg_list[0] = path_prefix + str(arg_list[0])
            arg_tuple = tuple(arg_list)
            return func(*arg_tuple, **kw)
        return dec_func
    return decorate

@render_decorate("%YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME%/")
def render_template(template_name_or_list, **context):
    return flask.render_template(template_name_or_list, **context)
```

Replace the %YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME% with your actual path, and ensure your templates folder is like this:
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DULuA.png)

And all done! Just use the render_template function as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this on fypress and fybb because I have a theme system.

```
# utils.templates
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
from flask.templating import _default_template_ctx_processor
from flask import current_app, url_for, get_flashed_messages


admin_env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('fypress', '/templates/admin/'),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape', 'jinja2.ext.with_'],
    autoescape=True
)

def render_template(template, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update(_default_template_ctx_processor())
    kwargs.update({
        'url_for': url_for,
        'get_flashed_messages': get_flashed_messages # etc...

    })
    kwargs.update(dict(debug=current_app.config.get('DEBUG'), flask_config=current_app.config))

    template = admin_env.get_template(template)
    return template.render(**kwargs)
```

And then

```
# routes.admin.
from flask import Blueprint
from utils.templates import render_template

admin_bp = Blueprint('admin', __name__,  url_prefix='/admin')

@admin_bp.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is what works for me. First search the template in the blueprint templates folder, if not found search in the app templates folder (for layout, etc.).

```py
from jinja2 import BaseLoader, TemplateNotFound
from flask import Flask, current_app, request

class BlueprintLoader(BaseLoader):
    def get_source(self, environment, template):
        for loader in (current_app.blueprints[request.blueprint].jinja_loader, current_app.jinja_loader):
            try:
                if loader:
                    return loader.get_source(environment, template)
            except TemplateNotFound:
                pass
        raise TemplateNotFound(template)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.loader = BlueprintLoader()
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to specify the *template_folder = "templates"* and then on rendering the template you would then specify the blueprint name as the parent directory as shown below

```
@users.route("/")
def users_index():
    return render_template('users/index.html')
```

Note that the above solution works only if you have created a sub-folder with the name of the blueprint first inside the templates folder which will be under your blueprint