# How to extend a base Flask Jinja template from a Blueprint template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am creating a fairly large application using Flask and Jinja.  Flask recommends separating large applications into smaller units using Blueprints.  If I have a base layout for my entire application/website, how can I extend this from templates within my blueprints?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You simply write name of the base template layout and Flask will find it if it exists in app's templates folder and then in blueprint's templates folder.

```
    {% extends 'template_name.html' %}
```

If it exists inside a folder in templates folder then

```
    {% extends 'folder_name/template_name.html' %}
```

If there are two templates with same name in app's templates folder and  blueprint's template folder, then template in app's templates folder will get priority.

See this question for more info [flask blueprint template folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7974771/679047)

Flask automatically finds templates for you if they are placed at right positions.

Comment: How do i get rid of this priority? I only want flask use exactly template i wanted with given path.