# Flask: Template in Blueprint Inherit from Template in App?

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I'm a total Flask/Jinja2 newbie, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, but:

Shouldn't Flask, out of the box, allow a template that exists in a blueprint's `templates/` folder to extend a base template defined by my app's `templates/` folder? Shouldn't this work even if the blueprint also includes a "default" base template, which I override by defining my own base template of the same name?

The answer to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11233959/1337498) makes me think that both of those things should absolutely be the case. Specifically the part of the answer that says:

> If there are two templates with same name[, one] in app's templates folder and [the other in] blueprint's template folder, then template in app's templates folder will get priority.

But it's not working that way at all for me. In fact, it seems to work the *opposite* way, i.e., the `base.html` from the **blueprint** is being pulled in by pages defined in my app, even though my app defines its own `base.html` (which should "get priority" if the above answer is correct).

In my app I have:

```
myapp/
   templates/
       base.html
       pages/
           page_base.html
           home_page.html
```

where `pages/home_page` extends `pages/page_base`, which in turn extends `base`.

I'm also using the `flask_user` package from PyPI, which was installed (by `pip`) at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_user/`. Its templates folder is arranged as follows:

```
flask_user/
    templates/
        base.html
        flask_user/
            [templates that extend base.html]
```

This package makes its templates available to applications that use it via a Blueprint which it establishes with the following calls in the `init_app` function of its `UserManager` class ([`__init__.py`, line 154](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/master/flask_user/__init__.py#L154)):

```
    # Add flask_user/templates directory using a Blueprint                  
    blueprint = Blueprint('flask_user', 'flask_user', template_folder='templates')
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

My initial thinking was that by defining my own `myapp/templates/base.html` I'd be able to customize pages rendered from templates in `flask_user/templates/flask_user/` to look like other pages in my app, because  (per the referenced answer) my `base.html` should take precedence over `flask_user`'s `base.html`.

But that's not working, and what's worse -- and much more surprising -- is that *my* app's pages are being given the default look of `flask_user`'s pages.

**Digging Deeper...**

Looking into @Pralhad Narsinh Sonar's suggestion that there may be a problem with the ordering of the template search paths, possibly caused by non-deterministic behavior of `DispatchingJinjaLoader._iter_loaders()` as suggested in the [fewstreet.com article](http://fewstreet.com/2015/01/16/flask-blueprint-templates.html) he cited, I did a quick experiment to see what ordering `_iter_loaders()` would produce for my app:

```
>>> from myapp.top import app, db
>>> from myapp.startup import init_app.init_app
>>> init_app(app, db)
>>> app.jinja_env.loader
<flask.templating.DispatchingJinjaLoader object at 0x7f233e396dd0>
>>> for loader in app.jinja_env.loader._iter_loaders('pages/home_page.html') :
...   print loader, loader.searchpath
... 
<jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader object at 0x7f233eb08490> ['/var/www/python/myapp/templates']
<jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader object at 0x7f233e36ef10> ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_user/templates']
```

As expected, the iterator yields the loader for my app's `templates/` folder *first*, before yielding the loader for `flask_user/templates/`. In fact, the `_iter_loaders()` function is quite deliberately structured to return the app's loader before returning *any* Blueprints' loaders. (If I'm reading the fewstreet.com article correctly, the problem it's concerned with is non-deterministic ordering among *multiple* Blueprints, which -- since there's only one Blueprint being used by my app -- isn't my current problem.)

This result makes it even harder for me to understand why `flask_user`'s `base.html` template is being used to resolve my template's `{% extends "base.html" %}` statement*. Given that I have my own `base.html` file in `myapp/templates`, I see no reason whatsoever for the templating system to look at anything in `flask_user/templates` to render `myapp/templates/pages/home_page.html`.

<sub>* For testing purposes I got rid of the indirection through `pages/page_base.html` mentioned above.</sub>

*So:* Obviously something else is going wrong, but *what*?

I haven't yet grokked enough of the relevant code in `flask/templating.py` or `jinja2/loaders.py` to understand why and how this might be happening. This being my first foray into Flask, I would have hoped I wouldn't need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**And the answer is:**

All this time I've been running (and reloading) my app with `debug=True`.

Which is great for automatically reloading changed Python modules.

But for changed *templates*? Um... not so much.

After introducing a breakpoint into my `home_page.html` template and using the Flask debugger to look back through a few stack frames, I discovered that Jinja2 makes use of an LRU cache to store (by name) templates it has already parsed.

Because I had hatched the idea of creating my own `base.html` template *after* having already loaded a `flask_user` page (`login.html`), which had originally inherited from `flask_user/templates/base.html`, there was *already* a template named `base.html` in the cache by the time I introduced `myapp/templates/base.html`.

So I **stopped and restarted the app**, and now both my `home_page.html` and `flask_user`'s `login.html` are correctly inheriting from *my* `base.html` instead of from `flask_user`'s `base.html`. I suspect that before I power-cycled the app, my own `base.html` had never even been *read* by my app's template loader.

This is a fairly significant -- and, I believe, *undocumented* -- gotcha for a newbie to have to figure out. I'll just leave this here, in hopes that it someday helps someone else who happens to step into this particular trap.

Answer (score 0):

**It will be tremendously helpful if you could share the `blueprint` section of your code.**

This could be the result of malfunctioning in search-path - wherein it treats first-in-line template as the one to be shown. To avoid this you can always rename the template files uniquely. If by any limitation or preference if you want to keep the identical names then you may please try with keeping the templates files under subdirectories of main template folder.

You may go through this link - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/

**Option # 1**

Please try with this structure of folders - you will also need to make changes in the `blueprints` -

```
myapp/
----templates/
--------base.html
--------pages/
------------page_base.html
------------home_page.html
----flask_user/
--------pages/
------------flask_user
----------------page_base.html
----------------home_page.html
```

More light on this problem in flask - **http://fewstreet.com/2015/01/16/flask-blueprint-templates.html**

**Option # 2**

```
myapp/
----templates/
--------base.html
--------pages/
------------page_base.html
------------home_page.html
--------flask_user
------------page_base.html
------------home_page.html
--------module_1
------------page_base.html
------------home_page.html
--------module_2
------------page_base.html
------------home_page.html
----flask_user/ # --> this is a module
-------- another module functionality
----module_1/ # --> this is a module
-------- another module functionality
----module_2/ # --> this is a module
-------- another module functionality
```

In the structure above each module will have its own routes file i.e. - `view.py` and hence separate `blueprint` configs to make each functionality modularized.

Please have a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications

Comment: I don't see how option 2 helps. It still moves the `flask_user` package into my `myapp` folder rather than leaving it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` where it belongs...

Comment: Also, regarding the linked article from fewstreet.com: My reading of the code of `_iter_loaders()` is that it ought to return my app's `jinja_loader` before it would return any Blueprint's loader. Which seems like it ought to result in exactly what the referenced answer promises, i.e., the "template in app's templates folder will get priority." I guess this would break down if `_iter_loaders()` was only called in response to the outermost `render_template()` call, but *not* for templates referenced by `extends` statements in already-loaded templates. But that would be stupid, right?