# use a single navbar file on multiple html files using a single tag in python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have navbar html template nav.html I want to use it on other html files.
I am creating a web application on pyhton flask.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsJt5.png)
I dont to write the same code on every page. I want to create once and user any where.

Comment: You can use the [include tag](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#include) to render a template in another template. However if your navigation is reused in all the templates, why not make a base template that they [extend](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#extends)?

Comment: That works, Great!! Why google not gave me that simple answer before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend a base Flask Jinja template from a Blueprint template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233959/how-to-extend-a-base-flask-jinja-template-from-a-blueprint-template)