# Deploying Flask App to Heroku - Template Not Found

Tags: python, heroku, flask, jinja2

I'm developing my first app with Flask and deploying to Heroku. Below is the error message I get locally and on Heroku. Also can be seen here: http://warm-beyond-4111.herokuapp.com/

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
>   TemplateNotFound: home.html

Longer version of the error here:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py",
line 61, in get_source raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: home.html
```

Here's an overview of the app:

Directory: /helloflask

Procfile:

```
web: python run.py
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.9
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
distribute==0.6.28
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

run.py

```
import os
from helloflask import app
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Directory: /helloflask/helloflask

__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
import helloflask.views
```

views.py

```
from helloflask import app
from flask import Flask, render_template
@app.route('/')
def home():
return render_template('home.html')
```

Directory: /helloflask/templates

home.html = a standard HTML file

Directory: /helloflask/static/css

main.css = standard CSS file

I've scoured the Interwebs for an answer with no luck. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the templates folder at the root of the application /templates and see if that fixes the problem.  I think you can set the templates folder in Flask, just can't find it now.

Also, you might like the github repo on flask deployment on Heroku.
https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku

Also checkout this SO Post on folder structure -
[flask blueprint template folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974771/flask-blueprint-template-folder)
You may want to use Flask Blueprints, if you prefer to keep templates under helloflask.

I don't use Flask on Heroku, so have not verified this setup.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `templates` folder should be a part of the package as your app. Move it into `/helloflask/helloflask`.

See #2 from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application.