# How do I find my template using Flask Blueprints?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I have searched everything I can find on SO including this, [flask blueprint template folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974771/flask-blueprint-template-folder).

```
/root
 __init__.py
 run.py
    /hrms
      __init__.py
      views.py
      models.py
    /static
    /templates
        __init__.py
        layout.html
        /hr
            __init__.py
            hr_template_test.html
```

I have also tried:

```
/hrms
  __init__.py
  views.py
  models.py
  /templates
      __init__.py
      hr_template_test.html
```

No matter where I put the `hr_template_test.html` file, Flask will not find it.  Here is what I have in `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

hrms_blue = Blueprint('hrms', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@hrms_blue.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('hrms_data_view.html')
```

In `run.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from application.views.hrms import hrms_blue

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(hrms_blue, url_prefix='/<hrms_id>')
```

I have tried:

```
return render_template('hr/hrms_data_view.html')
return render_template('application/templates/hr/hrms_data_view.html')
return render_template('templates/hr/hrms_data_view.html')
return render_template('hrms_data_view.html')

http://127.0.0.1/hrms
```

And Jinja2 complains it cannot find the html file.

I took out the `__init__.py` from templates and hr.  No I get, `TypeError: index() takes no arguments (1 given)`.

Comment: Your template folder should not have an `__init__.py` file in it. It is not a package.

Comment: I have tried it without it.  I will try again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters   I took it out and got TypeError: index() takes no arguments (1 given).  I've done this a billion times so I probably forgot I took it out and put it back.  Anyway, I get the new error.  (I have looked at your many answers here, still reading them.)

Comment: Your blueprint takes a route parameter but your view is not accepting it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please tell me what that means here.

Comment: You gave the blueprint a URL prefix: `url_prefix='/<hrms_id>'`. That's added in front of *any* route you register, so the `index()` view has the route `/<hrms_id>/`. Your `index()` view now needs to accept a `hrms_id` parameter.

Comment: If I put in this way, @hrms_blue.route('/<hrms_id>'), I get you can't use hrms_id twice.  I think I need to start over.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a issue with circular importing.
You should try doing:

```
def register(app):
    from __init__ import hrms_blue
    app.register_blueprint(hrms_blue)

register(app)
```

instead of doing:

```
app.register_blueprint(hrms_blue, url_prefix='/<hrms_id>')
```