# Structuring Flask using Blueprints error

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm attempting to break a small app into units and use the Blueprint pattern in Flask. However I seem to have trouble in getting the app running.

Here is my structure:

```
\myapp
  login.py
  \upload
    __init__.py
    views.py
```

Here is login.py:

```
import sys, os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, request
from flask import render_template, session
from .upload import views


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(views)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    print app.url_map
    print app.blueprints
    app.run(debug = True)
```

for `__init__.py`

```
    from flask import Flask
    app.register_blueprint('upload', __name__)
```

and in views.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
import views

upload = Blueprint('upload', __name__)

@upload.route('/uploaded', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    ...
```

Looking at the logs on heroku, here is the error:

```
from .upload import views
2015-09-05T10:59:00.506513+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Have a structured my package and blueprint correctly? I used the documentation, but I think I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

- You are using a relative import in `login.py` to include `views`, but given the folder structure and the fact that you use `login.py` as starting point, it cannot work here. Simply use `from upload import views` instead.
- The `__init__.py` references an unknown variable, `app`. You actually don't need anything in this file, remove everything.
- You try to register a module as a blueprint via `app.register_blueprint(views)` in `login.py`. This cannot work, a module is not a blueprint. Instead, import the `upload` variable defined in the `views` module, that is a blueprint: `app.register_blueprint(views.upload)`.

Changing that should get you started. Two side notes:

- You have an import in `views.py` that should probably not be there: `import views`. This should be harmless however.
- I answered a question about Flask blueprints some days ago, and gave an example about how to use them. Maybe would you find [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310580/flask-blueprints-how-to-use-them/32311791#32311791) useful in your case as well (in particular the part where the blueprint definition is moved to the `__init__.py` file defining the blueprint).

Comment: I made those changes, but now I get the problem: if blueprint.name in self.blueprints:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: It seems the blueprint cannot be same name as module?

Comment: Hmmm, wild guess: don't you have in the `views.py` file (below the section you copied in your question) a function called `upload` that would overwrite the `upload` blueprint defined at the beginning of the file?

Comment: I go round this by making my blueprint a different name to the 'module'.