# Flask Application Factory missing templates folder

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I converted some of my apps to application factory.  After converting the apps the templates folder can't be found.

```
/newsite
   wsgi.py
   config.py
   /application
      __init__.py
      /routes
        my_routes.py
        /templates
             index.html
      /templates
         index.html
```

In my `__init__.py`

```
....
from .routes import my_routes
app.register_blueprint(my_routes.route_bp)
```

In `routes/my_routes.py`

```
route_bp = Blueprint('route_bp',__name__,template_folder='static')
@route_bp('/home',methods=['GET'])
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Render templates fails.  The app does not know where the templates for is.  I added both template folders and added inth.html into both.  How can I know where flask thinks the template folder is located.?
I have printed `current_app.templates_folder` it only prints `templates` but how do I find the absolute path of the templates folder. So I can put my templates in the correct path.  I thought the path should be in the applications folder however that doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Setting `app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING']=True` may help.  This should print some useful info in the server console when you reload a page.

Comment: After adding the `app.config` it still prints `templates`

Comment: Setting `template_folder='static'` on the blueprint sounds wrong.  If removing that doesn't sort it, maybe also see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198325/2052575)

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  But it was a complete programming error I needed `render_template('index.html')` I had `render_template(index.html)`